# How to make radio :selected work in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, forms, radio-button

This works in Chrome but not in Safari:

```
require(['jquery'], function($)
{
    // store the value of the previous selected radio control 
    // before the current one gets selected
    $(document).on('focus', 'input[type=radio]', function () {
        // search all radio input fields with the same name within the same form
        // and store the value of active one into the oldValue property
        $(this).data('oldValue', $(this.form[this.name]).filter(':checked').val());
    });
});
```

Which part of the snippet is causing the trouble? I'm steppin' in the dark here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line:

```
$(this).data('oldValue', $(this.form[this.name]).filter(':checked').val());
```

to this:

```
$(this).data('oldValue', $(this).closest('form').find(':checked').val());
```

---

Other than this you can change `focus` event to `change`:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=radio]', function () {
```

Comment: that didn't fix my problem BUT it directed my attention to a more underlying problem: i put a console.log into the event block and didn't get it so it seems that the whole event is not fired when i'm using focus with safari, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TXLmk/

Comment: the fiddle is just this one line <input type="radio" onfocus="alert('focus')">
which doesn't work in safari

Comment: When a radio button is clicked on or tabbed to, Internet Explorer and Firefox fire the focus event. In WebKit, this event is not fired.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92029

Comment: @PhilS: Chrome 30 and Saf 5.1.7 on Windows Vista do fire the event. Even up to the point that Saf keeps firing it and one has to force-close the browser.